# Calcular fecha correcta del input de un usuario

Tags: javascript, html

solo tengo una pregunta. Me gustaría saber como puedo hacer que éste código funcione correctamente, me puse a hacerlo por curiosidad, no mas quería saber si se podía calcular si un año acaba en una cierta fecha.

Ví que se podía hacer por consola, pero me pregunte si se podía hacer algó parecido con el input de un usuario y mostrandolo en pantalla.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Calcular fecha</title>
</head>

<body>

<input type="text" id="date2" name="date2" class="date2"></div>

<input type="button"  value="Find"  onClick="Find()" /></p>

<div id="date1" name="date1" class="date1"></div>


<script>
var output = document.getElementById('date1');
var date2 = document.getElementById('date2');
this.output = date1;
this.date2 = date2;
var s2 = parseFloat(date2.value)

function Find(date2){


for (var year = 2018; year <= s2; year++)
{
var d = new Date(year, 0, 1);
if ( d.getDay() === 0 ){
    output.innerHTML = "El primero de Enero empieza el domingo en el año:  "+year;
}else{
    output.innerHTML = "El año colocado no empieza el domingo "+year;
}
}
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Por especificación se recomienda setear el valor a un elemento input haciendo uso del atributo .value, sin embargo para tu ejemplo, al establecer el value cambiaría tan rápido que no alcanzarías a ver toda la traza, podrías hacerlo en un textarea o con otro elemento de HTML, a continuación un ejemplo con un párrafo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Calcular fecha</title>
</head>

<body>

    
    <input type="text" id="date2" name="date2" class="date2" placeholder="Ingrese año mayor que 2018">
    <input type="button" value="Find" onClick="Find()" />

    <p id="output"></p>
    <script>
        function Find() {
            var source = document.getElementById('date2');
            var output = document.getElementById('output');
            var paramYear = source.value;

            var dateMatchWithSunday = (new Date(paramYear, 0, 1).getDay() == 0);
            var firstYearMatch = false;

            for (var year = 2018; year <= paramYear; year++) {
                var d = new Date(year, 0, 1);
                if ( d.getDay() === 0 ){
                  output.innerHTML += "El primero de Enero empieza el domingo en el año:  " + year + "<br/>";
                } else {
                  output.innerHTML += "El año colocado no empieza el domingo " + year + "<br/>";
                } 
            }
        }
    </script>
```